# Changing boot variables

Tags: switch

I'm new to networking/cisco gear and need some guidance. I'm gearing up to upgrade the code on a 3650 from 03.06.04E to 16.12.05b. I've done this once successfully but ran into a switch with a different boot variable set. The first time I performed an upgrade on a 3650, the boot variable was already set to flash:packages.conf. This particular switch is set to boot from flash:cat3k_caa-univeralk9.SPA.03.06.04E.152-2.E4.bin. When I attempted to set the boot variable to just flash:packages.conf, it appended it to the end of the original boot path. I'm trying to figure out how to safely clean it up so that it just shows flash:packages.conf. Below is how it looks currently. Can anyone give me any advice as to how to go about cleaning up the boot variable statement without messing things up further? I just want it to show flash:packages.conf. By the way, this is a single switch with no other members at a remote site and I don't want to take any chances with the current boot variable. Any help you can give is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

### Switch 1

Current Boot Variables:
BOOT variable = flash:cat3k_caa-universalk9.SPA.03.06.04.E.152-2.E4.bin;flash:packages.conf;

Boot Variables on next reload:
BOOT variable = flash:cat3k_caa-universalk9.SPA.03.06.04.E.152-2.E4.bin;flash:packages.conf;
Allow Dev Key = yes
Manual Boot = no
Enable Break = no

Comment: As with most Cisco devices, you can use the `no` keyword with a command to remove the command, then put in your own boot statement.

Comment: Thanks Ron for the quick response.